# (Java) Convert a decimal number into binary with a set bit amount

Tags: java, data-conversion

For some reason "null" is showing up within the bits that I'm trying to convert to 8 bits and I don't know why. I would think it is because I do not set numArray to anything?

```
/*
OUTPUT
null00000011
10110100
null00101011
null00000010
10110101
null00101010
*/
```

If there is something wrong that I am doing, please let me know below.

```
public class cache 
{
    static int [] ref = {3,180,43,2,181,42};
    static String numArr [] = new String[6];
    static String numArray [] = new String[6];
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //System.out.println(intToBinary(3,8));
        addZero(intToBinary());
        display();

    }

    public static String[] intToBinary()
    {

        for(int i =0 ;i<ref.length;i++)
        {
            //int num = in.nextInt();
            numArr[i]= Integer.toBinaryString(ref[i]);

        }
        return numArr;
    }
    public static void display()
    {
        for(int i=0; i< numArray.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(numArray[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void addZero(String[] me)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<me.length;i++)
        {
            int num = 8 - me[i].length();
            if(me[i].length()==8)
            {
                numArray[i]=me[i];
            }else
            {
                for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
                {
                    numArray[i]+="0";
                }
                numArray[i]+=me[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is a hint: declare the variables only in the scope in which they will be used. e.g. `numArr` is only used in  `intToBinary`

Comment: You use numArr for converting and printing another array, Is that normal?

Comment: I see what you mean @ScaryWombat. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that `null` plus `"0"` equals `null0`

```
numArray[i]+="0";
```

You could change it to

```
if (numArray[i].length() == 0)
  numArray[i]="0";
else
  numArray[i]+="0";
```

Answer (score 0):

The other real problem here: you lost track of the variables in your code.

You should either only use numArr - and with the code in place you would not even need your own conversion. Or you go with your own code - the one working numArray. But having both of these variables in your code is misleading and confusing.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You are welcome. And just for the record: dont forget about accepting the most helpful answer at some point. If I can do something to make my answer more helpful, let me know.